# XAMPP / MySQL / Undefined function mysql_connect()

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I am having a problem with a small class project. I have installed XAMPP, created the table that I need, loaded my *.sql database in it, but my project can't run because of some PHP issues I guess.

I had the $_SESSION problem, which I found a solution to, but then...

I am getting the famous:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\gabi\telk\DbSql.inc.php on line 11
```

But I can't bypass the problem. I have read other threads on this problem here but neither of them solves the problem for me.

Here is my code that is inside the DbSql.inc.php :

http://codepad.org/ToGmPB26

Comment: It's not the code, you don't have mysql extension installed, and you shouldn't be using it.  Use mysqli.

Comment: Is your version of XAMPP using PHP 7? If it is the `mysql_` extension has been removed from PHP7 never to be seen again. Use PDO or MYSQLI

Answer (score 0):

Check in your php.ini file if you have the line:

extension=php_mysql.dll

And it's not commented (with the ; in the line start)